# Preventing WCF Test Client from running

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2012

I'm developing a WCF Service with VS 2012

I'm using IIS Express.

If I run the service the WCF Test Client appears automatically.

I don´t find anything in the VS Options that allow me to turn the Test Client off.

How can I do that?

Comment: You will find solution here <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8441708/wcf-how-to-disable-wcf-test-client> and <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15252517/how-to-disable-wcf-test-client-vs-2012>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Project > Right Click > Properties > Debug >  Command line Argument`

Delete `/client:WcfTestClient.exe`

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. I don't find it. Is it in VS2012?

Comment: right click the project go to properties. should see this window.

Comment: I checked and this line-argument is not there. My solution is composed of: A class library containing the actual service. A Web Site that hosts the service, and a Console Application that consumes the service. I´m studying WCF Services. I don´t see the line argument /client:"WcfTestClient.exe" anywhere

Comment: Although I didn´t see it in my actual poroject, I saw it in other projects. Maybe my actual project isn´t a standard one. But I learnt how it´s done anyway.